# How do I look around?

Tags: elite-dangerous

How do I look left or right in my cockpit without actually turning my ship? I think this would greatly help my ability to line up for docks, but everything I push seems to turn my entire ship, even though I know there's a window there!

Comment: I use my middle mouse button to lock and unlock my "head" for default M+KB setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your control scheme, but there should be some keys bound to looking around. I'm not sure what the default is for keyboard, but if you're using a mouse, it's always enabled to use for looking around by default. There might also be a headlook key bound, which you'll need to toggle or press to look around with the specified controls.

Look in your game options and controls. The first section should describe whether the mouse is used for headlook, and the settings like sensitivity.

Further down there'll be a section that has the headlook key and looking around keybindings. I think it's near the UI section.

Comment: There's no default binding for keyboard. Pretty sure the default for mouse is for the middle button to toggle it.

Answer (score 2):

On Xbox one the toggle for headlook is right stick in.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. Don't know what you were downvoted for.